# Problem reading in some byte data into a Bitmap

Tags: .net, image, bitmap, stream

I'm trying to read in a hardcoded bitmap image into a bitmap object. I keep getting the same error:

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is
>   not valid.

This is the code i have...

```
const string fakeByteData = "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0+P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXV5fYGFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn+AgYKDhIWGh4iJiouMjY6PkJGSk5SVlpeYmZqbnJ2en6ChoqOkpaanqKmqq6ytrq+wsbKztLW2t7i5uru8vb6/wMHCw8TFxsfIycrLzM3Oz9DR0tPU1dbX2Nna29zd3t/g4eLj5OXm5+jp6uvs7e7v8PHy8/T19vf4+fr7/P3+/w==";

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fakeByteData));
var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
```

Yes, i've not used any '`using`' statements of disposed off stuff, because I was trying to see why this piece of byte data was erroring. This is some random code i have in a very temporary unit test.

I'm *assuming* the content of the `fakeByteData` is legit.

Can anyone shed some light, here?

Comment: What format is the bitmap supposed to be in?

Comment: er.. not sure .. nor do i care just yet. right now i just wanted to load in some random byte data for my unit tests. If my sample data is 'bad', then i'm happy with my problem because i can always source some new 'good' data. As such, I'm trying to understand what the error is _really_ about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a base64 string, but it *doesn't* have an image in it.

If you dump the data to disk after base64 decoding it, you'll find it's just bytes 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 etc right up to 0xff.

EDIT: To address your comment in the question: this is "bad" data in that it doesn't represent an image. You may want to have a unit test for such a case, but you can't write a unit test which expects a *real* image based on data which doesn't represent a valid image.

How will you be getting your image data in real life? Will it be as a base-64 encoded string? If so, here's some sample *valid* data for a red spot, taken from [the Wikipedia entry for the data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
string fakeByteData = 
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP"
    + "C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA"
    + "AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J"
    + "REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq"
    + "ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0"
    + "vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
```

Comment: so, the error i was getting was basically saying "the base64 data doesn't have an _image_ in it, so boom! error"?

Comment: Yes. You've asked it to load an image from that data (as a byte array by that point - it doesn't know it came from base64) and the data doesn't contain an image, hence the exception.

Comment: Thanks heaps Jon. I've learnt heaps from stalking your answers (all in a good way, mind you). You are a credit to the entire prgramming community. /me bows low. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You sure `fakeByteData` isn't [Base64-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)? That's usually the way to store image(binary) data as a string...

The "`==`" at the end of your string looks like the padding characters used in Base64 encoding as well.

What happens when you try:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(fakeByteData));
```

---

Update: I tried decoding `fakeByteData` using [an online decoder/encoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) and could not load the image. When viewing the contents, it looks like very fake data:

> �
>   !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ
>   ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ

This certainly shouldn't produce any kind of image I know; it appears to be a sequential array of bytes 00-FF. So I think your problem is in the data.

Comment: var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream) line. fails there. both mine AND yours.

Comment: @lc: It's not just "very fake data" - it's very predictable data: 256 bytes, 00-FF.

Answer (score 0):

Is the bitmap data an actual bitmap? To create a bitmap from a stream the stream must contain the data that is normally contained in a bitmap file. This includes headers and that stuff.

If the byte data is meant to give the actual image and not the entire file you should first create a new bitmap with the size you want and the image format you want. Then you should lock the bitmap using BitMap.LockBits and use Marshal.Copy to copy the byte data into the bitmap data. Alternatively you could use Bitmap.SetPixel and traverse the byte array manually, but that will be much slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
string fakeByteData = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP"
    + "C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA"
    + "AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J"
    + "REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq"
    + "ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0"
    + "vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(fakeByteData));
```

This helped me with my unit test to get the image